# Отслеживание изменения файлов и папок в Windows или свой мини-honeypot на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Для отслеживания изменений в системе на Linux для Python есть модуль [pyinotify](https://pypi.org/project/pyinotify/). Но она не работает на Windows системе. Есть ли аналог для windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, есть. Имя ему [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/).

К примеру:

```
import time
import sys
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler


class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.txt", "*.jpg"]

    def process(self, event):
        """
        event.event_type
            'modified' | 'created' | 'moved' | 'deleted'
        event.is_directory
            True | False
        event.src_path
            path/to/observed/file
        """
        # the file will be processed there
        print(event.src_path, event.event_type)  # print now only for degug

    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.process(event)

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path=args[0] if args else '.')
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

**PatternSatchEventHandler** наследует от **FileSystemEvent** Handler и предоставляет несколько полезных методов:

События: измененные, созданные, удаленные, перемещенные
*modified, created, deleted, moved*

on_any_event: если определено, будет выполнено для любого события
on_created: Выполняется при создании файла или каталога
on_modified: Выполняется при изменении файла или переименовании каталога
on_moved: Выполняется при перемещении файла или каталога
on_deleted: Выполняется при удалении файла или каталога.

Каждый из этих методов получает объект события в качестве первого параметра, а объект события имеет 3 атрибута.

- event_type

**'modified' | 'created' | 'moved' | 'deleted'**

- is_directory

True | False

- src_path

**path/to/observed/file**

Таким образом, чтобы создать обработчик, только унаследованный от одного из существующих обработчиков, для этого примера PatternClusterEventHandler будет использоваться для сопоставления только txt и jpg файлов.

Для упрощения я заключу файловый процессор только одним методом, и я реализую метод только для on_modified и on_created, что означает, что обработчик будет игнорировать любые другие события.